# Give bold to string

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this simple span with lines. I just want to bold the line that contains `Running test:`. **All line**

```html
<span id="results" style="white-space: pre-line">Running test: test1
asasggsa
fasfs
afasaggas
</span>
```

Any idea how do to it?

It should be something like

```html
 <span id="results" style="white-space: pre-line"><strong>Running test: test1</strong>
    asasggsa
    fasfs
    afasaggas
    </span>
```

Comment: it should be dynamic ofc.. like find the line that contains "Running test:" in results and bold that line

Comment: You're giving very little context. When do you want it to be bold? Do you want this happening on an onclick? Have you tried writing it yourself? Do you want the text to be displayed before running the test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `split` and `join`

**Demo**

```js
var value = results.innerHTML; //since results is an id
var textToBold = value.split( "\n" )[0]; //get the first line
results.innerHTML = value.split( textToBold ).join( "<strong>" + textToBold + "</strong>" ); //split by the text to bold and then join with enclosing tags
```

```html
<span id="results" style="white-space: pre-line">Running test: test1
asasggsa
fasfs
afasaggas
</span>
```

> I just want to bold the line that contains Running test:. All line

In that case use match

**Demo**

```js
var value = results.innerHTML; //since results is an id
var text = "Running test";
var linesToBold = value.split( "\n" ).map( s => s.includes( text ) ?  "<strong>" + s + "</strong>" : s ).join( "\n" );
results.innerHTML = linesToBold
```

```html
<span id="results" style="white-space: pre-line">Running test: test1
asasggsa
fasfs
afasaggas
</span>
```

Comment: not this. I dont know that is is test1 or whatever. I only know it contains `Running test:`

Comment: @user9478626 You mean only *bold* the first line? check the updates.

Comment: Then just input text that you know it contains inside the textToBold variable

Comment: there can be more Running tests. **not only on the first**

Comment: @user9478626 Check again.

Comment: @user9478626 Please do and revert.

Answer (score 0):

You can use pseudo element `::first-line`. But you need to change `span` to `p` as it can be used only with block level elements like so:

```css
#results::first-line{
  font-weight:bold;
}
```

```html
<p id="results" style="white-space: pre-line">Running test: test1
asasggsa
fasfs
afasaggas
</p>
```